# How to compile and link a C++ program into a DLL in runtime

Tags: c++, dll, linker, createprocess, entry-point

I am using `CreateProcess` to invoke `cl` and `link` to compile and link another C++ program (`TestProg.cxx`) into a DLL.

`TestProg.cxx` contains the following `DllMain` function:

```
extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

and I added `/Entry:DllMain` to the link options.

I get the following linkage errors:

```
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMain

main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown

main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase

main.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Could you please let me know how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: My guess is that you're seeing problems with C++'s name-mangling.

Comment: Unlikely; `extern "C"` is the correct way to indicate that you want C, not C++ name mangling. But even C has name mangling, as you can see from the leading `_`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the CRT (C runtime library). It provides the `__RTC_Shutdown` function, for instance. When you link it in, it's started before your `DllMain` by wrapping it. This will also solve your first link error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tested my code with using `/LD` on copmilation options, with and without the `/DLL` option on the linkage options, I got the same linkage errors. Without both I got the error `LINK : fatal error LNK1221: a subsystem can't be inferred and must be defined`. Using `/SUBSYSTEM` link option seems wrong since it: `Tells the operating system how to run the .exe file`, but when I added it the same link errors appear again. Please let me know how to add the CRT (I didn't find a /CRT option). Thanks!

Comment: @ZOK: The usual solution is to pass `/MT` to the _compiler_. There are multiple versions of the CRT, and the linker choice should match the compilers. Therefore the linker reads from the .obj file what the compiler did. But as I already told you earlier, you probably shouldn't be invoking the liner anyway and leave that to CL.exe

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't invoke the linker, I leave that to `cl`. Passing `/MT` to the compiler, I got the error: `LINK : fatal error LNK1221: a subsystem can't be inferred and must be defined`. Passing `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` to the linker brings the 3 linkage errors again. Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Easiest approach would be to create a simple Visual Studio DLL project. Visual Studio will show the effective command line paramaters to CL.